# STM32L031 only starts up in debugging mode but otherwise does not run

Tags: stm32

I'm facing a weird problem. I've created a custom board with the STM32L031G6U6 chip on it and some additional circuits. The software acts completely weird on this board while working without problems on a Nucleo board with the same microcontroller (in another package.)

The biggest difference I can spot between the Nucleo and my own board is the missing crystal, although the datasheet states that it isn't required due to internal oscillators.

The code I tested is as simple as possible. It should only toggle the pin of the `STATUS_LED`. That's it.

- If I step through the code, everything seems to work.
- If I try to press `continue` on the STM32Cube IDE, nothing happens. The execution seems to stop.
- If I press `run` in the IDE, nothing happens. The code never gets executed.

Since I'm at a state where I think the code is no problem, since it works on the same processor in the nucleo board, it must be the schematic.

I tried on three PCBs of the same design with the same problems on all of them. The PCBs were manufactured and assembled at JLCPCB.

It would be very nice if someone sees a fault with my circuit which can be the reason for my problems.

Here is my schematic. I don't post the code for the `TOUCH` net since it is only a button connecting the pin to ground when pressed.

[image: STM32L031G6U6]

[image: Additional circuit]

Comment: Please provide the code. Just in case. Put some breakpoints in code, see which line you reach. Check boot0 and reset voltages

Comment: Your code, or rather, if it is generated by CubeIDE, might assume a crystal.

Comment: I will provide the code tomorrow. @Ilya If I'm in debugging mode, I can reach everything, except if I click "continue", then it's over.

Comment: @Justme Crystal ist turned off. The source is LSI for internal oscillator. The other clock can be set to MCI and HSI. As noted before. The same code runs on the nucleo board.

Comment: "I can reach everything, except when I press continue". This statement looks like self-contradiction to me. If you put a breakpoint on your second line of code, does it stop there? And what do you mean over? You have a while(1) loop in the program, it should never be over. How exactly over? Press pause during debugging and see where you end up. Could be hardware fault handler or something. That might give some info about where to look.

Comment: Try putting a pull-up resistor on the reset line.

Comment: @Ilya If I press continue, I can add a break point somewhere in the while loop but it will never stop again. If I press pause, I'm in some memory areas I  don't know, but I never get to the code in the while loop. Over means, I cannot get back to normal stepping in my code. There might be a problem with the main loop. I can step through the while loop as often as I want, but after pressing continue I never get back to the code and the LEDs are turned off and never get back on again.

Comment: @JohnBirckhead Shoudn't be necessary. It isn't installed in the Nucleo board since the reset pin is pulled up internally. Putting another resistor just reduces the overall resistance on this pin since it is put parallel the already existing resistor.

Comment: @who9vy I understood very little from your reply, when you press pause, you will likely end up in some function like "hardware fault handler". You may need to play-pause multiple times. Maybe add a code of part you are at when you press pause. Or a screenshot. Don't look at the memory address you're in, look at the function you're in first when you pause. Can look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEtkh.png

Comment: You are right, but I was just worried that your debugger has control of the reset line.  Your code won't run with the processor standalone (without the IDE)?

Comment: @Ilya That is exactly the problem, I end up nowhere and I can resume and pause as often as I would like, I'm always ending up in some unknown register. Here is my screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/Fg1Nsa0

Comment: @JohnBirckhead No, it doesn't run without a connected debug probe and without stepping through the code. I can disconnect everything and just connect the voltage source and nothing happens. And the thing is, that the same code for the nucleo board on the nucleo board just works.

Comment: Maybe, it is because `HAL_SYSCFG_GetBootMode()` always returns 256 (0x100) when it doesn't work and 0 when it works. But how to set the boot mode? I thought that is set by the BOOT0 pin which is pulled down to GND.
That can definitely be the problem. But why does it work like this?

Comment: Ok, it is definitely the problem. I can repeat this every time. It has something to do with the reset type (RSetType 0 not working and RSetType 2 working). But if I disconnect and reconnect power supply, it also doesn't work. I assume that in this case `` `HAL_SYSCFG_GetBootMode()` will return 0x100 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The Altium package I downloaded was for the wrong package of the STM32L031. It is for the STM32L031G6U6S and not the STM32L031G6U6.